# What to choose for Yii based website: subdomains pointing to modules or separate yii-applications

Tags: module, yii, subdomain

I'm making a website on yii which has several separate parts, each on it's own subdomain like themes.example.com, events.example.com etc with main page example.com where these parts are listed. I will also need to authenticate users across subdomains. So i'm thinking what would be better: making each part as a yii module or making a separate yii application for each of these parts?

Comment: wiser or more convenient and in a way that will allow appropriately  use yii as a framework

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case it would be better to use modules. At least to have a single webroot directory. Using separate yii application would be appropriate for console part of your project.
See this link for more information: [The directory structure of the Yii project site](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/155/the-directory-structure-of-the-yii-project-site/)

Comment: thank you! and that article about the directory structure helped me a lot

Answer (score -1):

Well,

The features you are trying to accomplish from Yii its called "Parameterizing Hostnames". You need to create a module based structure in Yii.

At first you need to create a virtual host from apache and redirect that to your Yii project. On you Yii framework you need to change the URL manager from config.

```
'components' => array(
   ...
   'urlManager' => array(
      'rules' => array(
         'http://admin.example.com' => 'admin/site/index',
         'http://admin.example.com/login' => 'admin/site/login',
      ),
   ),
   ...
),
```

To know more about [Parameterizing Hostnames](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url)